# How do I fix Array.prototype.map() expects a return value from arrow function array-callback-return warning?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

The below js is throwing a warning when I run eslint.

```
bills.map((bill) => {
    if (bill.val) {
      total += bill.val;
    } else {
      total += 0;
    }
  });
```

**eslint** warning: *Array.prototype.map() expects a return value from arrow function  array-callback-return*

When I try changing {} to () like:  `map(() => {}) to map(() => ())` I get a "*declaration or statement...*" error msg in my IDE.

```
bills.map((bill) => (
    if (bill.val) {
      total += bill.val;
    } else {
      total += 0;
    }
  ));
```

How do I get past this warning?

Comment: Return something from your arrow function. Looking at your code, you want `forEach` rather than `map`.

Comment: Use `forEach` instead if you don't intend to `return` something